# macOS fetching computer name programmatically

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, hostname

I'd like to find how to extract my computer name programmatically, similar to the output of following terminal command `scutil --get ComputerName`. This value can also be found under "About this mac" -> "System Software Overview" as shown in the following image :

[image]

So I've found one way is to use NSHost, but it's long been deprecated:

```
[[NSHost currentHost] localizedName]
```

In NSHost.h it mentioned where to look for ..

> Use Network framework instead, see deprecation notice in <Foundation/NSHost.h>

So I've looked there and found `nw_endpoint_get_hostname` but it has no proper documentation for how to be used to fetch local hostname.

Any Idea how to fetch this data programmatically (swift/objective-c/c++)

Comment: I Actually saw this question, but they propose a way that has long been deprecated.

Comment: Did you see any of the _other_ solutions in that post? I can see some Swift solutions in there that are not outdated...

Comment: Does the `uname()` C library routine not work?  See `man 3 uname`

Comment: `ProcessInfo.processInfo.hostName` can be what you are looking for?!

Comment: The key for me was `import SystemConfiguration` and `let name = SCDynamicStoreCopyComputerName(nil, nil)`. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1517208-scdynamicstorecopycomputername).

Comment: If you use Swift, `Host.current().localizedName` is not deprecated and will return the computer name just as formatted in the System Software Overview.